# Simple query hangs on a specific column condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have two servers, and I a dumped the database of the first to restore it on the second.

Everything works great, except that on the second server, I can't do any selection based on a specific column "user_id" anymore : `SELECT * FROM products WHERE user_id = 12 limit 1;`

Each time I run it on the second server, it stays still, without any error. And every other request that concerns a selection based on the user_id column is also stuck (`where user_id IS NOT NULL`, etc.).

I launched mysqlcheck, everything seemed ok, I restarted mysql, but nothing works.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this ?

EDIT :

Curiously, `SELECT * FROM products WHERE user_id IS NULL limit 1;` works fine.

Comment: I suppose you are using MyISAM for that table? Is the table locked by another process? Can you provide the EXPLAIN for a problematic select? In which state does the query hang (SHOW PROCESSLIST)? Can you provide the table structure and how many rows do you have? Have you checked the filesystem for disk problems?

Answer (score 2):

I might be guessing on this one, but I think the key distribution must be insane.

### POSSIBILITY #1

Please run this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT IFNULL(user_id,-1) user_id,COUNT(1) prod_count
    FROM products GROUP BY IFNULL(user_id,-1)
) A ORDER BY prod_count DESC;
```

If you can send the output to a text file, look for user_id 12 and compare its `prod_count` to the total number of rows in the `products` table. My guess is that user_id 12 is probably more than 5% of the table. The Query Optimizer would give up using any index on user_id and just do a full table scan. To make sure that is the case, please run

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM products WHERE user_id = 12;
```

### POSSIBILITY #2

There may be stale index stats and you need to run

- `ANALYZE TABLE products;` if there are a lot of INSERTs, UPDATEs.
- `OPTIMIZE TABLE products;` if there are a lot of INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs.

### GIVE IT A TRY !!!